# Jackson: quoting non-numeric numbers inconsistency

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've found an inconsistency in the writeNumber() method in the Jackson JSON processor library.  Calling writeNumber(String) on "NaN" with QUOTE_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS enabled fails to return a quoted string.  This is illustrated in the following example:

```
float nan = Float.NaN;
try {
    JsonGenerator jg = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(System.out);
    jg.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS);

    // writeNumber(String s)
    jg.writeNumber(""+nan);

    // writeNumber(float f) 
    jg.writeNumber(nan);

    jg.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

actual output:

```
NaN "NaN"
```

expected output:

```
"NaN" "NaN"
```

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior, even if seemingly unintuitive. This is due to strict definition of numbers in JSON specification, coupled with potentially open-ended set of numbers that Java has; it is hard to match both safely and conveniently.

In first case, you are printing "raw" number, using exact formatting you want. No quoting is added, as result is assumed to be valid JSON number. If you want double-quotes, you will add them. This is similar to `writeRaw()`, except that it is explicitly a value write, meaning that necessary separators (commas in arrays, semi-colons between property name and value) are also added.

In second case it is known that value you are to output is not a valid JSON number, and it must be printed as a JSON String.